# Given very long binary, convert it to decimal

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, data-conversion

First, this is a part of my hw. Second, this is only a part of it, so I would really appreciate any hints here.

I've implemented a kind of BigInt class, which stores numbers as sequences of zeros and ones - stores decimal as a binary.

My class can add numbers and multiply them.

Ok, but when I multiply two large numbers, I get a huge number.

My question is - given a really really long binary number, how do I convert it back to decimal?

I've found something about dividing by 10, but I'm not sure, if that's my case... Or it is, and I have to implement binary dividing?

Thanks...

Comment: What is your desired format? Do you want to have a float/double that is close to your number? Do you want to have the exact number as a string? You could simply build a generic version of your class, working with a different base, e.g. 2 or 10.

Comment: I want to print out the exact (decimal) number as a string. I tried to search a little bit more and I've found a double dabble algorithm. What do you think about it? Can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

binary means base `2` so if you have for example `10100` and you need the base `10`you could apply the following pattern, going from the last element to the first (right to left): `2^0*0 + 2^1*0 + 2^2*1 + 2^3*0 + 2^4*1 = 20` you just raise 2 to power `a` starting from `0` to `length_of_binary_num-1` and you multiply that power with the binary digit from your string(right-to-left) or you have aditional method on

[Convert Binary to Decimal](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal)

also I would recommend using a string for binary since binary digits tend to look more like strings than integers

Comment: The problem is, I can't use this method, because i can't sum so huge numbers - I need to print the number out, but I can't sum them, because there is no type, which can hold such huge numbers...